# turtoise svn set user rights

Tags: svn, rights

My question is how can I set some user rights to a branch in the SVN?

For an example I use the folder A in the SVN  which I have already checkout it and also my collegue too.
But we want only we to have access this folder with read\write rights.

I do not have ssh console access. Only web svn view. From where and how I can manage the user rights?
SVN - TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, Build 22907 - 32 Bit , 2012/05/15 12:16:05

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TortoiseSVN is **Subversion client**, and can do nothing with **Subversion server** tasks (ACLs for repository access)
2. Usable solution are dependent from enabled RA-layers (file:/// svn:// or http:// access protocol) - you mention nothing about this topic
3. All solution require from you to have rights of server's administration
4. [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is useful reading, at least [Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) for beginning